# org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate can't print out query built

Tags: sql, ibatis

I'm using SqlMapClientTemplate to execute a complex query.

> getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("myComplexQueryName", params);

"myComplexQueryName" is a query in xml file with my conditions and parameters.

The question is

how to log/print out the query built?

I'm expecting something like:

> String getExecutedQuery("myComplexQueryName", params);

So I can debug what's executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to output the result of your query, I think you just have to put a list where you can store the values from the executed query like this:

```
List<Object> result= new ArrayList<Object>();
        try {
         //Your query here
       result= this.getSqlMapClient().queryForList(""myComplexQueryName", params);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

:)

Comment: No I want the query string itself. It may be very complex with conditions and parameters. I want a way to output the query to be executed.